# How to Map Complement on two sets of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

This problem was easy I thought, but I can't solve it, I have two lists

```
t = Range[{5, 7}]
k = {{3, 5},{2,7}}
```

and I want to get

```
{Complement[Range[5], {3, 5}],Complement[Range[7], {2, 7}]}
```

giving
{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
I tried double pure functions, but to no avail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you'll want `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[Complement, {t, k}]
```

> `{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}}`

Comment: +1 Also, `Complement @@@ Transpose[{t, k}]`

Comment: Oh yes, this one. Thanks!